# Adding a row into a new element based on the name of another column

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to place the three groups in PlantGrowth into 3 separate datasets to make 3 boxplots (using base r, but I am fine using ggplots as well). Currently my idea is to use an `if` function, but as I'm not too used to R it isn't working out how I want it to.

[image]

Currently I'm working on something along the lines of this to place them separately. Is there an easier way to do this? Or maybe a way to make the if function work?

Comment: You want to use the `ifelse()` function. Also, please do not post pictures of code. Rather copy and paste it as part of your question, and if possible provide an example of your data using `dput()` or provide an example using a publicly available data set, like `iris`, `mtcars`, etc.

Comment: @Phil 100% agree RE not using images -  note that `PlantGrowth` is a provided dataset in R, similar to `iris`and `mtcars`([see here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/datasets/versions/3.6.2/topics/PlantGrowth))

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to separate into three different datasets to get three box plots. If you want them in all three in separate, individual plots, you can use `sapply` (or a `for` loop), which will iterate through the different levels and output a separate box plot for each group:

```
sapply(unique(PlantGrowth$group), 
       function(x) boxplot(PlantGrowth[PlantGrowth$group %in% x, "weight"], 
                           main = x))

# or 
for(plnt in unique(PlantGrowth$group)){
  x <- PlantGrowth[PlantGrowth$group %in% plnt, ]
  boxplot(x$weight, main = plnt)
}
```

This will output three individual plots like below (using `trt2` as an example since it was the last output, but similar for the other two groups):

[image]

If you want them all faceted in one visual, you can use `par` and `mfrow`:

```
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
sapply(unique(PlantGrowth$group), 
       function(x) boxplot(PlantGrowth[PlantGrowth$group %in% x, "weight"], 
                           main = x))
```

[image]

For completeness, of course if you want them all on the same plot you can simply do:

```
boxplot(PlantGrowth$weight ~ PlantGrowth$group)
```

[image]